# Jackson JSON not able to deserialize array of elements with custom root name?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a Json that looks like this:

```
{
  "testEntities" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "floatNumber" : 0.006117165,
    "floatNumberObject" : 0.15273619,
    "intNumber" : -1155869325,
    "intNumberObject" : 431529176,
    "doubleNumber" : 0.41008081149220166,
    "doubleNumberObject" : 0.20771484130971707,
    "shortNumber" : 9364,
    "shortNumberObject" : 13977,
    "booleanValue" : true,
    "booleanValueObject" : true,
    "byteValue" : -79,
    "charValue" : "e",
    "charValueObject" : "b",
    "creationDate" : 86400000
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "floatNumber" : 0.9874208,
    "floatNumberObject" : 0.45285606,
    "intNumber" : -1154715079,
    "intNumberObject" : 1260042744,
    "doubleNumber" : 0.9014476240300544,
    "doubleNumberObject" : 0.49682259343089075,
    "shortNumber" : 483,
    "shortNumberObject" : 18322,
    "booleanValue" : false,
    "booleanValueObject" : true,
    "byteValue" : -73,
    "charValue" : "c",
    "charValueObject" : "r",
    "creationDate" : 172800000
  } ]
}
```

When I attempt to deserialize it, it fails with:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'testEntities' does not match expected ('TestObject[]') for type
```

I already enabled array deserialization:

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY);
```

Clearly, `testEntities` is a custom name that Jackson knows nothing about. The `TestObject` class has a custom annotation I created called `JsonRootNamePlural`, to be used when the root element is a collection instead of a single instance:

```
@JsonRootName("testEntity")
@JsonRootNamePlural("testEntities")
public class TestObject {
   ...
}
```

This annotation is needed in other places of the system as well.

I want it to use it the same way it uses the `@JsonRootName` annotation, except that for arrays. So It could look for the root element   as indicated by JsonRootName, and if none is found, it could look for @JsonRootNamePlural. All other root names in the JSON should be ignored by Jackson.

The question is, **what should I override or customize to introduce this behavior?**

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer for my own question: Need to set on the object mapper a custom instance of `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` which override the `findRootName` method, and there check if the class is array and if so look for the custom annotation in the array component class, like so:

```
    @Override
    public PropertyName findRootName(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        // if this is an array, look for JsonRootNamePlural annotation in
        // the base type for the array (the so called array component)
        if (ac.getRawType().isArray()) {
            Class<?> arrayComponent = ac.getRawType().getComponentType();

            JsonRootNamePlural ann = arrayComponent.getAnnotation(JsonRootNamePlural.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                return PropertyName.construct(ann.value(), null);
            }

        }

        // super class will look for default @JsonRootName annotation
        return super.findRootName(ac);
    }
```

Hope this will help others,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot!) You realy help! I am new for annotation creating, so I will write how i do it maybe it will be easy  to create their own.
It's an annotation class:

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JsonRootNamePlural {
    String value();
}
```

My Introspector class:

```
class ArrayRootNameAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public PropertyName findRootName(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        if (ac.getRawType().isArray()) {
            Class<?> arrayComponent = ac.getRawType().getComponentType();

            JsonRootNamePlural ann = arrayComponent.getAnnotation(JsonRootNamePlural.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                return PropertyName.construct(ann.value(), null);
            }

        }
        return super.findRootName(ac);
    }
}
```

And JsonUtil class:

```
     public static Object readArrayFromJson(String responseString,Class arrayClazz) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new ArrayRootNameAnnotationIntrospector());
            mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(responseString, arrayClazz);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

Pleae note that arrayClazz variable in readArrayFromJson() method should be class of array(For example MyObject[].class)